# How to create ascending number and letter order columns names

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyr

I have complex header names columns

```
 [1] "Proszę podać, ile godzin dziennie oglądasz zazwyczaj treści VIDEO wymienione wyżej, BEZ PRZERYWANIA INNĄ AKTYWNOSCIĄ.\r\n"                                             
 [2] "oglądanie treści video, w tym granie w gry video, itp....12"                                                                                                           
 [3] "słuchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp....13"                                                                                                
 [4] "edukacja - czytanie lub wykonywanie zadań związanych ze szkołą/studiami, itp. "                                                                                        
 [5] "pisanie e-maili lub wysyłanie postów w social mediach, itp. "                                                                                                          
 [6] "wysyłanie SMS lub korzystanie z komunikatorów internetowych i czatów, itp. "                                                                                           
 [7] "rozmowa przez telefon lub komunikator video, itp. "                                                                                                                    
 [8] "Proszę podać, ile godzin dziennie słuchasz zazwyczaj treści AUDIO wymienione wyżej, BEZ PRZERYWANIA INNĄ AKTYWNOSCIĄ. \r\n"                                            
 [9] "oglądanie treści video, w tym granie w gry video, itp....19"                                                                                                           
[10] "słuchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp.2"
```

I am stopping here to the tenth, but the naming is reiterated since after columns whose name starts with "Proszę.." there is a subset of columns:

```
 [2] oglądanie treści video, w tym granie w gry video, itp....12"                                                                                                           
 [3] "słuchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp....13"                                                                                                
 [4] "edukacja
```

What I would like to do, is to create a code that renames the "Proszę" column into a column named "Primary" and then followed by each singular alphabet letter. For example

```
1) position number 1: this would be converted in "Primary A"
2) position number 2: this would be converted into "PrimaryB"
```

the other subset I would like they become converted like this:

1. oglądanie in position 2: as "Second A"
2. the one in position 9: "Second B"

and so on with the number and letter succession. I have the problem that not always is easy to recognize the unique occurrence of each item, due to complex wording. So it would be better to have a solution that exploits just reiterated elements of each column.

If you want I leave un a small example of dataset here.

```
dput(head(MMT[,25:34], 1))
structure(list(`Prosze podac, ile godzin dziennie korzystasz zazwyczaj z materialów do CZYTANIA wymienionych wyzej, BEZ PRZERYWANIA INNA AKTYWNOSCIA.
` = "mniej niz 1 godzine", 
    `ogladanie tresci video, w tym granie w gry video, itp.2` = "nigdy", 
    `sluchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp.3` = "okolo 3- 4 godzin", 
    `czytanie lub wykonywanie zadan zwiazanych ze szkola/studiami, itp.2` = "okolo 1-2 godzin", 
    `pisanie e-maili lub wysylanie postów w social mediach, itp.2` = "mniej niz 1 godzine", 
    `wysylanie SMS lub korzystanie z komunikatorów internetowych i czatów, itp.2` = "okolo 1-2 godzin", 
    `rozmowa przez telefon lub komunikator video, itp.2` = "nigdy", 
    `Prosze podac, ile godzin dziennie  spedzasz zazwyczaj na czytaniu i pisaniu MAILE I POSTY na social mediach wymienionych wyzej, BEZ PRZERYWANIA INNA AKTYWNOSCIA. 
` = "mniej niz 1 godzine", 
    `ogladanie tresci video, w tym granie w gry video, itp.3` = "nigdy", 
    `sluchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp....34` = "okolo 2-3 godzin"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the data frame as `dat`, try the following.
You can be as general or specific as you like with `grep()`--below is just an example.

```
> i <- grep('^[Pp]ros', names(dat))
> i
[1] 1 8
> 
> names(dat)[i] <- paste('Primary', letters[1:length(i)])
> names(dat)
 [1] "Primary a"                                                                  
 [2] "ogladanie tresci video, w tym granie w gry video, itp.2"                    
 [3] "sluchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp.3"         
 [4] "czytanie lub wykonywanie zadan zwiazanych ze szkola/studiami, itp.2"        
 [5] "pisanie e-maili lub wysylanie postów w social mediach, itp.2"               
 [6] "wysylanie SMS lub korzystanie z komunikatorów internetowych i czatów, itp.2"
 [7] "rozmowa przez telefon lub komunikator video, itp.2"                         
 [8] "Primary b"                                                                  
 [9] "ogladanie tresci video, w tym granie w gry video, itp.3"                    
[10] "sluchanie muzyki, audycji radiowych, podcastów, audiobooków, itp....34"
```

If you have many pairs (old -> new) you could do something like this:

```
oldnames <- c('something', 'else', 'nothing')
newnames <- c('new1', 'new2', 'new3')

for (i in 1:length(oldnames)) {
  j <- grep(oldnames[i], names(dat))
  names(dat)[j] <- paste(newnames[i], letters[1:length(j)])
}
```

There are many possible variations on this approach.

Comment: thanks. What if, as in my I should enter more than one name in the grep() function? could you please extend a little your example just showing what to do with 'ogladanie'? Does this code will rename the columns in dataset?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, `names() <- ` will change the column names. About ogladanie, it depends on exactly what you need. If you would like to replace it with "Primary" as well, you can use the "or" operator `|` in `grep()`. If not, but you only have a few different phrases/letter combinations you would like to replace in this way, I would just duplicate and modify the solution given above for "pros". If you have many,  you might organize them (search pattern and replacement text) in vectors or a data frame and then apply in a loop or analogous. Let me know and I/someone can try to explain more.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Here is a general example: `i <- grep('Original_pattern', names(dat)) ; names(dat)[i] <- paste('New_name', letters[1:length(i)])`. The `^` in `grepl()` means the start of the string, the `[aA]` means either a or A. You can copy and modify this. Each one will replace *all* column names that match. I'll add a loop approach to the answer that would be more efficient for many pairs.

Comment: Your example is fine to change one variable at once. If you need want to replace all or two the columns in one shot, how  would you modify the code?

Comment: sorry, just now I realized you've posted your loop. I am going to test it ;)

Comment: your code works great. Many thanks. There is a small issue with the letters. For each subset I have always the same letter A